# Pojo to DTO - Bean Mapping

Tags: java, javabeans, mapper

I gone through stackoverflows, ModelMapper, Dozer etc..
I couldn't figure out the existing logic to map Entity to DTO.

The following are the classes for the Entity and DTO:

```
package com.entity;

public class EmployeeRequest {

    private User user;
    private String userId;

    public EmployeeRequest(){
    }   
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.entity;

public class User {

    private Address address;
    private Name name;

    public User(){
    }
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.entity;

public class Address {

    private int flatNo; 
    private String city;

    public Address(){
    }
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.entity;

public class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(){
    }   
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.dto;

public class EmployeeRequestDTO {

    private UserDTO user;
    private String userId;

    public EmployeeRequestDTO(){
    }
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.dto;

public class UserDTO {

    private AddressDTO address;
    private NameDTO name;

    public UserDTO() {
    }
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.dto;

public class AddressDTO {

    private int flatNo;
    private String city;

    public AddressDTO() {
    }
    //Getters and Setters Below
}

package com.dto;

public class NameDTO {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public NameDTO(){       
    }
    //Getters and Setters Below
}
```

//Mapping Class:

```
package com.service;

import com.dto.EmployeeRequestDTO;
import com.entity.Address;
import com.entity.EmployeeRequest;
import com.entity.Name;
import com.entity.User;

public class EntityModelMapperService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Address address=new Address();
        address.setFlatNo(72);
        address.setCity("Kayalpatnam");

        Name name=new Name();
        name.setFirstName("Abdul");
        name.setLastName("Basith");

        User user = new User();
        user.setAddress(address);
        user.setName(name);

        EmployeeRequest employeeRequest = new EmployeeRequest();
        employeeRequest.setUser(user);      
    }
}
```

How to map entity values to DTOs? Once assigned, any changes in entity should not affect DTO and viceversa.

Comment: you can use e.g. [model mapper](http://modelmapper.org/)

Comment: How about just writing the necessary code? It's just a matter of calling constructors and copying fields. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed assigning values :( I got it now. Thanks Piradian and JB Nizet

Comment: @JBNizet - Is it safe to use ModelMapper?

Comment: You can, of course. But my experience with such mappers is that they're a major source of complexity and bugs, make your code fragile and impossible to refactor safely, just to save a few lines of trivial code.

Comment: When I copy values from entity to DTO via ModelMapper, it is taking 129320562 nanoseconds. When I copy normally, it is taking 77949 nanoseconds. Is it good to go?

Answer (score 2):

The below 1 line is enough to map:

```
EmployeeRequestDTO employeeRequestDTO = new ModelMapper().map(employeeRequest, EmployeeRequestDTO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have a look at [ModelProjector](https://github.com/glaures/modelprojector) for this. It supports exactly the use cases you are envisioning with very little footprint and extra-coding.